# How to insert micro seconds to MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, time

I'm creating flash game. From game I get data to PHP and I need insert It to database. So I get Time value in format 0:00.000 [minutes:seconds.micro seconds]. How to successfully insert It to database? My SQL table's type is time. And here is format 00:00:00 [hours:minutes:seconds].

Problem is that if I get time from game 11 seconds 279 micro seconds (from game format 0:11.279) It to database insert 11 minutes only [00:11:00].

How to insert to database normal format [minutes:seconds.micro-seconds]?

My code looks like:

```
   <?php 
            $time= $_POST['time'];
            $username = $_POST['userName'];

            $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","asd","asd","asd");
        if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT into myTable (time, userName) VALUE (?,?) ")) {

 if (!$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")) {
            printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
        } 
        $stmt->bind_param('ss', $time, $name);

           $stmt->execute();

           if ($stmt->error != '') {
               echo ' error:'.$stmt->error;
           } else {
               echo 'success';
           }
           $stmt->close();
        } else {
           echo 'error:'.$mysqli->error;
        }
        $mysqli->close();
```

**UPDATE:**

How my Time column looks like in database:

[image: db]

Comment: `microtime(true);` with PHP but then you have to store is as integer not datetime

Comment: Thank you for answer, in which place I need to put this line?

Answer (score 1):

You should create the time colum with microseconds using

```
TIME(number of decimals)
```

You could find more info here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html

Edit:
As I sugest in the comments you could store it in decimal and edit the input and the output.
Here is an example to do it.

```
$initial_value='11:02.234';
$exploded = explode(':',$initial_value);
$to_insert = $exploded[0]*60+$exploded[1];

echo "value to insert $to_insert";
```

To transform the mysql decimal output to your format use:

```
$value_from_the_db ='234.123';
$tmp = floor($value_from_the_db/60);
$to_print = $tmp .':' . (($value_from_the_db-$tmp * 60)>10?($value_from_the_db-$tmp * 60):'0'.($value_from_the_db-$tmp * 60));

echo "Value to show = $to_print";
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, I updated my question, how my database column "Time" looks like. Could you say me how I need to edit It? Thank you.

Comment: In `Length/Values` put `6` which specifies 6 decimal places, aka microsecond precision.

Comment: I've tried It, but after I put 6 to Lenght/Values and click save button, It says that successfully saved, but after I click edit again this field is blank again. Also It still show format 00:00:00 and I've tried to insert Time from game for now It was 0:12.351 and It inserted 00:12:00.

Comment: Which PHP version are you using? Before PHP 5.0 you can't use fractional seconds.

Comment: Sorry for stupid question, but I don't know which version of PHP here is. Full code I pasted in my question.

Comment: You could know the PHP version your server is running by executing echo phpversion();

Comment: I saw that If type is "Time" and in Length/Values field I type any number, nothing changes. But If type I change from "Time" to "Decimal" I can set Length/Value for 10,6 and It formatting to 0.000000, but still is wrong I need 0:00.000

Comment: Thank you for information. Version: 5.3.3-7+squeeze19

Comment: Anyway I will sugest you to use a decimal field to count the seconds. With a time field you will never be able to save values bigger than 24h.

Comment: So how can I correctly setup decimal field? What Length/Values I need to set to insert 0:00.000 format?

Comment: I've edit the answer to give you some PHP code to do it in a decimal field

Comment: Thank you for answer, now It insert correct, but how now to select data from MySQL? In previous method in select from database 0.000

Comment: I've edit my answer. After getting the decimal value from the DB you should transform it to your format with the second PHP code